# Intel Pin trace specific function calls

Tags: c++, intel-pin

Is there any way to trace calls to a certain function by a thread in Intel Pin. I am following this example ManualExamples/malloc_trace.cpp and replaced malloc with a function in my application program, but it dosen't seem to work. Also this example uses routines and I am interested in finding out the thread that invoked this function call. Is there any other way?

Comment: The second paragraph appears to be an independent question. I suggest you ask a seqond question fro that, but do explain exactly how you're doing it. The usual reason for a segfault on `argv[]` is by reading outside array bounds.

Comment: oh I got it, I was reading a wrong location. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll remove the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered this problem as well. I compared my program carefully with malloc_trace.cpp. Then I found that it did load symbol and if I ignore that operation, pin would not find my specific function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize pin & symbol manager
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv)) return Usage();
```